# Error using connector.internal.autostart.run Can't reload ibmwmathlinalg.so

Tags: c++, matlab

I got this error while using Matlab as an external engine in C++ code. There are several reasons why this could happen. [Some say](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/242197-what-are-these-errors-on-starting-up-matlab) about lack of permission of various folders. While my case was not due to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was due to missing file libgfortran.so.3.0.0 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu This was rectified by reinstalling gfortran using:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```